# Substitute values of a row in a dataframe by the values of a vector coming from a function using R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to replace the existing values of a row in a tibble by the values in a vector of the same size using dplyr (or similar) functions.

In my real problem I have a tibble `df` which contains some `NA` missing values, like:

```
df <- tibble(
  column1 = c(1, 5, 10),
  column2 = c(2, NA, 12),
  column3 = c(NA, 7, NA),
  column4 = c(4, 8, 16)

)
```

I want to fill those missing values with interpolated values. I could do something like the following, which works fine:

```
num_col <- ncol(df)
x_interp <- seq(1, num_col, 1)

for (idx_row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[idx_row, ] <- as.list((spline(x_interp, df[idx_row, ], xout = x_interp, method = "natural")$y))
}
```

But in reality I have 150000 rows and 20 columns, and the for loop takes a while.

Can anyone propose a way to do the same using dplyr functions?

Any idea? Thank you!

I have tried something like this, but it does not work:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                spline(x_interp, across(everything()), xout = x_interp, method = "natural")$y))
```

I expect to get this result in the previous example:

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       1       2       3       4
2       5       6       7       8
3      10      12      14      16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you what you want, and pretty quickly, assuming the `NA` values are not in the first or last column:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
  column1 = c(1, 5, 10),
  column2 = c(2, NA, 12),
  column3 = c(NA, 7, NA),
  column4 = c(4, 8, 16)
  
)

approx_df <- 
  apply(df, 1, function(x) approx(1:length(x), x, 1:length(x))$y) %>%
  t() %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() 

names(approx_df) <- names(df)

> approx_df

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  column1 column2 column3 column4
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       1       2       3       4
2       5       6       7       8
3      10      12      14      16
```

But two things...  First, when you use `tibbles` or `data.frames` in R, you'll want to put your data series in columns not rows, because each column in a `tibble` or `data.frame` is an atomic vector (like you get from `c(1,2,3)`).  When you work across rows, you are working across vectors.

Second, there is a package `xts` (extensible time series) based on a package called `zoo`.  Both are really useful for working with series-based data.  If you have a look at those packages and learn how to use them, you will save yourself tons of time in the long run.  Your series will have to be arranged in columns, but, for instance, there is an `zoo::na.approx()` function that interpolates time series, so you don't have to write messy, difficult to read code (like the mess I made above). ;-)

EDIT:

I missed the fact that you were looking for a `dplyr` solution.  But again, like `xts` and `zoo`, `dplyer` is designed to use series in columns rather than rows.  In fact, the structuring of your data is paramount to success in R in general and with the "tidyverse" in specific.  (`dplyr` is a foundational package in the "tidyverse.") This link will get you started with creating tidy data:

https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

If you "tidy" your data, then you won't be fighting with `dplyr`. Instead, it will work seamlessly.  For instance:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~seriesA, ~seriesB, ~seriesC,
  1,        5,        10,
  2,        NA,       12,
  NA,       7,        NA,
  4,        8,        16
)

> df %>%
  mutate(
    across(everything(), function(x) approx(1:length(x), x, 1:length(x))$y)
  )

 seriesA seriesB seriesC
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       1       5      10
2       2       6      12
3       3       7      14
4       4       8      16
```

Comment: Hi Geoffrey,

Thank you very much for the suggestion and the explanation. The issue is that I wanted the data in the matrix form and not in tidy form because I want to run a PCA on it. But probably it makes good sense to "tidy" the data, compute the interpolation as you are suggesting, and set it back into matrix from again to perform the PCA. Or alternatively I can try to perform the PCA in the tidy form directly, as shown here: https://clauswilke.com/blog/2020/09/07/pca-tidyverse-style/

In any case your suggestion was extremely useful. Many thanks!